# Changing the color of navbar-brand to two colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to change the `navbar-brand` so that the two words are two separate colors. I am having trouble doing that at the moment as no matter what CSS I use it doesn't seem to change the color. The padding I used does take effect so it is targeting it, just not changing the color. Could anyone help me with what I need to do?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fluid" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><div class="translation">TRANSLATION</div><div class="commons">COMMONS</div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav pull-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Donate</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SPAN` and assign a color.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fluid" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="red">TRANSLATION</span> <span class="white">Commons</span></a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Well done and forgive my pickiness.  

Always a good idea to have color classes not be named a color.  So for example instead of .red you should use another color-agnostic descriptor like .significant or whatever.  This way, when it comes time for a redesign or if someone in test says this should be orange, you don't get yourself confused.  

All that said, I know this is an example.

Comment: @shubniggurath This is merely to illustrate a point and nothing more, I think that's generally obvious.

Comment: @vanburenx You know that and I know that.  Folks will just copy or mimic our examples though.  You did nothing wrong of course, and as I said I knew it was an example.  I was just leaving the comment for future viewers more than anything.